# Yii 1.1.19 Join Table Update not working fully

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

The Problem: If I select the new checkbox, it will update the data, but when I unchecked all the existing checkbox, it is not working. Even when I unchecked multiple checkboxes and leave one, it still works. Just not working when I select all unchecked checkbox to update data. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

This is my model that I am using get join table ID:

```
public function getProfileCampaigns($campaignIds = true) {
    $campaignData = array();
            $campaignProfiles = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->select('campaign_id')
                                                ->from('campaign_profiles')
                                                ->where('profile_id = :profile_id',array(':profile_id' => $this->profile_id))
                                                ->queryAll();
    // Check if need to send only campaign ids
    if ($campaignIds) {
        foreach ($campaignProfiles as $campaignProfile) {
            $campaignData[] = $campaignProfile['campaign_id'];
        }
    } 

    return $campaignData;
}
```

This my controller for update action:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $model->setScenario(Profile::SCENARIO_UPDATE);
    // Get active campaigns
    $campaigns = Campaign::model()->findAll();
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    // Check if profile have any releated profile
    $model->campaignIds = $model->getProfileCampaigns();

    if(isset($_POST['Profile']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Profile'];
        if($model->validate()) {
            $model->save();

            // Check if any campaign choosed
            if ($_POST['Profile']['campaignIds']) {
                Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->delete('campaign_profiles', 'profile_id = :profile_id', array(':profile_id' => $model->profile_id));
                foreach ($_POST['Profile']['campaignIds'] as $campaignId) {

                    $campaignProfile = new CampaignProfile();

                    $campaignProfile->setIsNewRecord(true);
                    $campaignProfile->campaign_id = $campaignId;
                    $campaignProfile->profile_id = $model->profile_id;
                    $campaignProfile->save();
                }
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'The Profile was successfully updated.');
                $this->redirect(array('update','id'=>$model->profile_id));
            }

        }
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model' => $model,
        'campaignListData' =>$campaigns,
    ));
}
```

This is form for getting checkbox select for update:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'campaignIds'); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <?php echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'campaignIds', CHtml::listData($campaignListData, 'id', 'name')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'campaignIds'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because only selected checboxes are send as form data. When no checkbox is checked, no data is sent, so probably default/old value from model is used.

You may use `uncheckValue` setting to define default value which will be send, when no checkbox is checked:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'campaignIds'); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <?php echo $form->checkBoxList(
            $model,
            'campaignIds',
            CHtml::listData($campaignListData, 'id', 'name'),
            ['uncheckValue' => '']
        ); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'campaignIds'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Since 1.1.7, a special option named 'uncheckValue' is available. It can be used to set the value that will be returned when the checkbox is not checked. By default, this value is ''. Internally, a hidden field is rendered so when the checkbox is not checked, we can still obtain the value. If 'uncheckValue' is set to NULL, there will be no hidden field rendered.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeCheckBoxList-detail

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had to use your solution plus afterSave() function in the model to make it work. Greatly appreciated it.